# why isnt my $row[userID] printing?

Tags: php, mysqli

in my code im trying to print basically "Logged in as ***_*__**!!!!!!!!!!" if a persona successfully logs in. I have no clue why this syntax isnt working and saw alot of previous posts working with it.

Primarily this line: echo "Logged in as **".$row['userID']."**!!!!!!!";

what im esepcially confused by is why "echo $row" isnt printing anything. It should print out all the information from that row right?

The rest of the code is here:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['user']))
{
    //variable declaration 
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    //connect to data base 
    $con=mysqli_connect("engr-cpanel-mysql.engr.illinois.edu","socialdrinkers_b","testing123","socialdrinkers_db");

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Drinker where userID = '$user' AND password = '$pass'");
    echo mysqli_error($con);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >0)
    { // correct info
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
        {//cookie implementation
            $expire = time() + 60*60*24; //1 day
            setcookie('idNum', $row['idNum'], $expire);
            echo $row;
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Logged in as <b>".$row['userID']."</b>!!!!!!!";
        }
    }
    else{ // wrong info
        echo "<b>wrong id or pass</b>";
    }
}


echo "<form method = 'post'> 
Username: <input type = 'text' name = 'user'>
Password: <input type = 'password' name = 'pass'>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'LOG IN'> 
</form>";
```

?>

Sorry Im asking soo many questions, this is my first time building a database oriented website and our professor in our class didnt give very clear tutorials on the specifics of how this works.

Comment: Unfortunately, this site is not an online class either. Questions like "why my code doesn't work" are plain offtopic here.

Comment: sorry about that, ill try to figure out how to ask more productive questions next time

Answer (score 0):

You should use :

> mysqli_fetch_assoc

instead of

> mysqli_fetch_array

beacause you want to get information in associated model not array model ;)

Comment: and remember try to find your errors first and say your problem exactly here tanx ;)

Comment: it doesnt say any errors though, it just prints Logged in as !!!!!!!

and the mysqli_fetch_assoc didnt fix the issue

Comment: You should check the manual page *before* issuing an answer like this.

Comment: try var_dump($row) and write it content here